# Rtsp streaming on nodejs - Blank screen

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am currently working on a Node.js project where I need to implement streaming using ffmpeg. However, I am facing an issue with the streaming process, as I am getting an empty blank screen instead of the expected video stream.

Here's a brief overview of what I have done so far on the server-side:

Installed ffmpeg and made sure it is accessible in the environment.
Configured the server-side code for the streaming process.
However, despite these efforts, the stream is not working correctly, and I am unable to see the video stream on the client-side.

Server-side code:
app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

// Start the RTSP stream
const stream = new Stream({
  name: 'rtsp_server_name',
  streamUrl: 'rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4',
  wsPort: 3000,
  ffmpegOptions: {
    '-stats': '', // an option with no necessary value uses a blank string
    '-r': 30, // options with required values specify the value after the key
  },
});

stream.on('data', data => {
  console.log(data);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
  <h1>Test rtsp video</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsmpeg.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:3000', {
      canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'), // Canvas should be a canvas DOM element
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

I got no console error when I open index.html but only get blank black screen
[image: Blank Screen]

Comment: Your shown link `rtsp://wowza ... BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4` doesn't work. Try loading a link that you've seen **actually working** correctly (_eg:_ a link that works in VLC player on your desktop)

Comment: I found a working link but now I have some errors  
"[rtsp @ 000002588426e8c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options"
Do you have any idea why ? @VC.One

Comment: Is your new found link sending Mpeg-1 video (as the codec)? Can you open it in VLC? If yes to VLC then open it there and look under **Tools** --> then under **Codec Information**. What video codec/format does VLC say your link is using? If it's not MPEG-1 then you cannot play it using JSMPEG.

Comment: I am seeing that the format is "H264 - MPEG-4 AVC". Is there any way to convert it MPEG-1 or any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your stream should be playable in a `<video>` tag, but it won't connect to RTSP servers. What happens if you go to `http://localhost:3000` in your browser? Does the browser start showing (or saving) anything? If yes, then use that same URL as the `src` of the video tag and see if it plays.

Answer (score 0):

Not use localhost. Use local ip your PC.
Open CMD and write `ifconfig`. IP4 your machine ip.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
  <h1>Test rtsp video</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsmpeg.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://192.168.0.100:3000', {
      canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'), // Canvas should be a canvas DOM element
    });
  </script>
</html>
```